# Detect cancellation of context menu

Tags: python, wxpython

For my app I need to detect, if a user cancels a Context `menu`, for example with Escape `key`.

```py
import  wx

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Right Click for Context menu")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.OnContextMenu)

    def OnContextMenu(self, event):
        self.popupID1 = wx.NewId()
        self.popupID2 = wx.NewId()
        self.popupID3 = wx.NewId()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnPopup, id=self.popupID1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnPopup, id=self.popupID2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnPopup, id=self.popupID3)

        #how to detect/bind event ...? to call OnPopupCanceled if menu is cancelled
        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.Append(self.popupID1, "One")
        menu.Append(self.popupID2, "Two")
        menu.Append(self.popupID3, "Three")

        self.PopupMenu(menu)
        menu.Destroy()

    def OnPopup(self, event):
        print "Item Selected, event id: ", event.GetId()

    #this should be called, it user exits the menu through escape key
    def OnPopupCanceled(self, event):
        print "Popup Menu cancelled"

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None)
TestPanel(frame)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

How can I achieve that? Obviously there is no possibility to bind on an Escape/Cancel event.

Comment: May I ask why do you need this? Usually, if the user Cancel the context menu it means that the GUI should do nothing.

Comment: Because I need to set/restore focus to a special window/control, if the user cancels the menu (and some more small thins). I just need this. In my case, the popup menu is displayed, if the systray Icon is pressed. I don't want to explain now more accurately, my question is only, if it is possible to detect exiting the menu without select anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch the event, `wx.EVT_MENU_CLOSE`. Add the line:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU_CLOSE, self.OnPopupCanceled)
```

to your `OnContextMenu` method.

You should notice that this event will also be sent if the user cancels the menu by clicking outside the menu.

You can find more details [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.MenuEvent.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, in the mean time I found another possible workaround (very easy):

```
        self.user_select = False # add this
        self.PopupMenu(menu)
        menu.Destroy()
        print self.user_select #here set 

    def OnPopup(self, event):
        print "Item Selected, event id: ", event.GetId()
        self.user_select = True ```

Comment: sorry, I have problems in formatting the code and now I cannot edit anymore. To explain in short: set a variable in the menu handler, if a menu item was chosen (in OnPopup). If after the call self.PopupMenu this variable is not set, then the user has cancelled the popup menu.

Comment: @fst Yes, that is another way to do it.